# How to build query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the next schema for my user records:

```
{ 
    "last_name" : "First Name", 
    "first_name" : "Last Name", 
    "age" : 30.0, 
    "country" : "Canada", 
    "hobby" : [
        "running", 
        "skating", 
        "skiing"
    ]
}
```

How can I build query, to get all users that have at least the same hobbies, that user with last name 'X' does?

I've tried something like this, but it didn't work.

```
db.users.find({
     last_name : { $ne: "X"},
     hobby: {$all: db.users.find({
       last_name: "X"
     },{hobby:1, _id:0})} 
})
```

Comment: @turivishal So the idea there to get all other users, that have the same hobbies as the user X

Answer (score 0):

- Find user where `last_name` is "X" and store in a variable called `x_user`, and project required fields
- Find users where `last_name` is not "X" and `hobby` should be equal to `x_user`'s `hobby`

```
var x_user = db.users.findOne({ last_name: "X" }, { hobby: 1 });
db.users.find({ 
    last_name: { $ne: "X" },  // or use - _id: { $ne: x_user._id }
    hobby: {
        $all: x_user.hobby
    }
})
```